# Let $G$ be a ﬁnite abelian group of odd order. Which of the following deﬁne an automorphism of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a ﬁnite abelian group of odd order. Which of the following deﬁne an automorphism of $G$?

a. The map $x→ x^{−1}$ for all x ∈ G.
b. The map $x→ x^2$ for all x ∈ G.
c. The map $x→ x^{−2}$ for all x ∈ G.

---

I have verified that all of them are homomorphism.
(a) it is bijective since each element in a group must have inverse and it is unique.
But I could not verify other two are bijective or not.
how can I able to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2$.let $g\in G$ be an arbitrary element and $o(g)=l$. So there are $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $2x+ly=1$. Thus $g=g^{2x}$.

$3$.As you know, the composition of two automorphisms are an automorphism.

Answer (score 1):

For part (b), let $x^2=y^2$ for some $x,y\in G$. Then $(xy^{-1})^2=e$. If $x\neq y$, then $xy^{-1}\in G$ has order 2, which is not possible. So we must have $x=y$. Thus $x\rightarrow x^2$ is one-one. Now, using the fact that any self-map on a finite set is injective if and only if it is surjective, it follows that $x\rightarrow x^2$ is an automorphism. The map in part (c) is a composition of the automorphisms defined in part (a) and (b), and hence an automorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of both your homomorphisms consists of all the elements whose square is one. Any such element, other than one, is the generator of a cyclic subgroup of order two. But according to Lagrange, there can be no such subgroup, so the kernel is trivial, and the homomorphisms are automorphisms.