# Show that the map $f(a)=a^2$ is an isomorphism of groups from G to itself.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a commutative group of odd order.

Show that the map $f(a)=a^2$ is an isomorphism of groups from G to itself.

$f(ab)=(ab)^2=a^2b^2=f(a)f(b)$ so clearly its a homomorphism.

Now suppose $f(a)=f(b)$.

Then $a^2=b^2$.

Multiply on the left by $a$.

$a^3=ab^2$ and since G is odd, $a^3 =e$.

So $e=ab^2$. Then multiplying by $b$ on the right,

$eb=ab^3$ and $b^3 = 1$ so $a=b$. It is injective.

How do we show it is surjective?

Comment: You are not given $a^3=e$, so your proof of injectivity is flawed.  Anyway, once you proved injectivity it is just counting elements.

Comment: How $a^3=e$?...

Comment: To show injectivity of homomorphisms is somewhat easier than for general functions. You may actually assume that $b=e$ and just show $f(a)=e\implies a=e$.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/622962/29335

Comment: oh yeah, i thought it meant every element has an odd order

Comment: Actually, every element **does** have odd order because its order divides the order of the group which is assumed to be odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the kernel?  If $a^2=e$, then $a=e$.  Otherwise $\vert a\vert=2 \Rightarrow \Leftarrow $.

Comment: How do we get injectivity from this?

Comment: See @Arthur's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is not correct $$a^2=b^2 \implies a^2b^{-2}=e \implies (ab^{-1})^2=e$$ so order of $ab^{-1}$ is either one or two and  by hypothesis, it is one and so $a=b$

Now  the map from a finite set to itself is one to one, so it is surjective as well!